# Creating labels simultaneously on 2nd form through 1st form

Tags: vb.net, forms

Hi good day guys i would just like to ask a question because I want to create a label on second that do have the text that I put into textbox1 of the first form and I want to do it simultaneously for example after I added text to label in form2 i would add another label and text again with the same method.I tried figuring it out for 3 hours but still no luck .here is the codes..Thanks in advance guys

```
    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Dim frm2 As New Form2     'Create your Form
    Dim lbl As Label = New Label     'Create your Label
    lbl.Location = New Point(50, 50) 'Set Label Location
    lbl.Text = TextBox1.Text         'Set Label Text
    lbl.ForeColor = Color.Black       'Set Label ForeColor
    frm2.Controls.Add(lbl)           'Add Label to it
    frm2.Show(Me)                    'Show Second Form

End Sub
```

i have no intentions of having a form2.show command because I do have another button for showing the 2nd form..but when I remove it it produces error.

Comment: Your code seems ok, what error do you get? Or what happens that you didn't expect?

Comment: @Matt Wilko yes the codes are correct but I want to add labels simultaneously not only ones...thanks

Comment: What do you mean simultaneously?

Comment: @Matt Wilko I mean after I add a text from form1 using textbox to form2's label i want to add another again and another again..using the same method :)

Comment: Just run the same code again and put the label in a different location

Comment: @MattWilko Sir I cant do that because if I remove the frm2.Show(Me) the debugger wont allow me. I have another button for showing form2 that is why I am having this problem right now sir..thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code in the class..

```
Private frm2 As New Form2

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Dim lbl As Label = New Label     'Create your Label
    'change the location..    
    lbl.Location = New Point(50, 50) 'Set Label Location
    lbl.Text = TextBox1.Text         'Set Label Text
    lbl.ForeColor = Color.Black       'Set Label ForeColor
    frm2.Controls.Add(lbl)           'Add Label to it

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    if frm2 IsNot Nothing Then
        frm2.Show(Me)            'Show Second Form  
    End If      
End Sub
```

Comment: Sir this codes works but how could I put another label with a text after i added the first label with a text? because after I added the second label it produces error. Thanks!

Comment: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Form2'.

Comment: the first one is functioning well but after I add another label that error shows ^ thanks :)

Comment: once you close the Form2 it get disposed. I recommend you to get some online tutorials for working with multiple Winforms.

Comment: No..once I clicked the button again it gets disposed because I want to add another label...

Comment: do you want that all added labels remain in Form2? if yes then the code is working for me here, if no then you have to create a new form on each click on button3.

Comment: Sir Yes I want all the labels that I will be creating be stored in one form which is form2 :) multiple labels in form2 using the button on form1 and the textbox there :) thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46843/discussion-between-sarvesh-and-thenewbie)

Comment: if you dont want to show multiple objects of Form2, don't create new object.

Comment: @Manu Viswam because I also need to edit the interface of the form sir

Comment: what i mean is if you want to show only one instance of Form2, you dont have to create an object by using Private frm2 As New Form2